# GDI sprite shown some time and disappear

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+, gdi

I'm studying sprite drawing with GDI in Visual Studio 2013 with C++.
I can draw sprite using two bmp files, image with black background, and black mask. But after program start, sprite shown some time (about 15 second) and disappear. I can't find the reason.
Here is my code.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
using namespace std;

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);
HWND hWnd = 0;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_HAND));
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ASTERISK));
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = "ClassName";
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        MessageBox(0, "Class was not registered!", "Error", 0);

    hWnd=CreateWindow("ClassName", "WindowName", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInst, 0);
    if (hWnd==0)
        MessageBox(0, "Window was not created!", "Error", 0);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (msg.message!=WM_QUIT)
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        HDC hdc = GetDC(hWnd);
        HDC hBuffDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hBuffBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 640, 480);
        HBITMAP hSpriteBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_MASK));

        SelectObject(hBuffDC, hBuffBitmap);
        SelectObject(hBuffDC, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));
        Rectangle(hBuffDC, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hSpriteBitmap);
        BitBlt(hBuffDC, 0, 0, 640, 480, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCAND);
        hSpriteBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SPRITE));
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hSpriteBitmap);
        BitBlt(hBuffDC, 0, 0, 640, 480, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 640, 480, hBuffDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

        DeleteObject(hBuffBitmap);
        DeleteObject(hSpriteBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        DeleteDC(hBuffDC);
        ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
    }

    return 0;
}

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

images are just a black circle with white background (mask), and green circle with black background.

Comment: You are currently loading the bitmap each frame. Load the bitmap outside your loop and use it like you're using it now. Move the delete functions to be run after your just before the return 0.

Comment: Thank you Eejin. I change code like you say and it's ok now. But i can't understand, where was a leak in original code? In the end of each frame i release/delete all resourses gained in the begining.

Comment: I've checked results of DeleteObject, DeleteDC and ReleaseDC. ReleaseD(hWnd,hdc) failed. Seems that it was a leak.

Comment: I got it. ReleaseDC need window handle. But in my code it is called after window destroyed. After i moved Release DC right before PostQuitMessage - it was completed successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Here is corrected code without memory leak and ReleaseDc return 1

#include <Windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
using namespace std;

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam);
HWND hWnd = 0;
HDC hdc = 0;

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory(&msg, sizeof(msg));
    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_HAND));
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ASTERISK));
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = "ClassName";
    wc.lpszMenuName = 0;
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClass(&wc))
        MessageBox(0, "Class was not registered!", "Error", 0);

    hWnd=CreateWindow("ClassName", "WindowName", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 640, 480, 0, 0, hInst, 0);
    if (hWnd==0)
        MessageBox(0, "Window was not created!", "Error", 0);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    hdc = GetDC(hWnd);

    while (msg.message!=WM_QUIT)
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    else
    {
        HDC hBuffDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HDC hMemDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
        HBITMAP hBuffBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, 640, 480);
        HBITMAP hSpriteBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_SPRITE));
        HBITMAP hMaskBitmap = LoadBitmap(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_MASK));

        HBITMAP hOldBuffBitmap= (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hBuffDC, hBuffBitmap);
        HBRUSH hOldBrush= (HBRUSH)SelectObject(hBuffDC, (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(GRAY_BRUSH));
        Rectangle(hBuffDC, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        HBITMAP hOldSpriteBitmap= (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemDC, hMaskBitmap);
        BitBlt(hBuffDC, 0, 0, 640, 480, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCAND);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hSpriteBitmap);
        BitBlt(hBuffDC, 0, 0, 640, 480, hMemDC, 0, 0, SRCPAINT);
        BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, 640, 480, hBuffDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
        SelectObject(hBuffDC, hOldBuffBitmap);
        SelectObject(hMemDC, hOldSpriteBitmap);
        SelectObject(hBuffDC, hOldBrush);

        DeleteObject(hBuffBitmap);
        DeleteObject(hSpriteBitmap);
        DeleteObject(hMaskBitmap);
        DeleteDC(hMemDC);
        DeleteDC(hBuffDC);
    }
    return 0;
}

LRESULT WINAPI WinProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch (wParam)
        {
        case VK_ESCAPE:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        }
        return 0;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        int Res = ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc); //Release main window device context before destroying window
        DWORD err = GetLastError();
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```